# Raid 5 overwritten with Fedora server installation

Tags: raid

I have mistakenly installed Fedora server on my RAID 5 rahter on a SSD.
Now the raid is not mounting:

```
# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raid
mount: /mnt/raid: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid5
  ├─md0p1   259:14   0 199.5M  0 md
  ├─md0p2   259:15   0     1G  0 md
  ├─md0p3   259:16   0   7.8G  0 md
  └─md0p4   259:17   0   5.5T  0 md
sdb           8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid5
  ├─md0p1   259:14   0 199.5M  0 md
  ├─md0p2   259:15   0     1G  0 md
  ├─md0p3   259:16   0   7.8G  0 md
  └─md0p4   259:17   0   5.5T  0 md
sdc           8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid5
  ├─md0p1   259:14   0 199.5M  0 md
  ├─md0p2   259:15   0     1G  0 md
  ├─md0p3   259:16   0   7.8G  0 md
  └─md0p4   259:17   0   5.5T  0 md
sdd           8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid5
  ├─md0p1   259:14   0 199.5M  0 md
  ├─md0p2   259:15   0     1G  0 md
  ├─md0p3   259:16   0   7.8G  0 md
  └─md0p4   259:17   0   5.5T  0 md
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   7.8G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    50G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 179.5G  0 part  /home
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa3cc0309

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xed8ce2fd

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3d7e7ce7

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x105b1153

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 3907029167 3907027120  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 9B5B3FC7-C545-4AE7-94A4-D1B2BFCB006D

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    411647    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    411648   2508799   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3   2508800  18849791  16340992   7.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4  18849792 123707391 104857600    50G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5 123707392 500117503 376410112 179.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/md0: 5.5 TiB, 6000793878528 bytes, 11720300544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1572864 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E95D6E40-653D-4E3B-AD23-473266AB7890

Device        Start         End     Sectors   Size Type
/dev/md0p1     3072      411647      408576 199.5M EFI System
/dev/md0p2   411648     2509823     2098176     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/md0p3  2509824    18849791    16339968   7.8G Linux swap
/dev/md0p4 18849792 11720294399 11701444608   5.5T Linux filesystem

cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdd[4] sdb[0] sdc[2] sda[1]
      5860150272 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 6f619c94:6b307950:3fdba8c6:4f42b906
           Name : localhost.localdomain:0
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 20 12:14:37 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860150272 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766848 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a1d9b5ed:86165a6d:d89c58e5:eb920479

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul 13 15:53:28 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : afaddf01 - correct
         Events : 65852

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 6f619c94:6b307950:3fdba8c6:4f42b906
           Name : localhost.localdomain:0
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 20 12:14:37 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860150272 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766848 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : d3a9e0cc:a3d59a4f:25bba234:b9d61ef3

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul 13 15:53:28 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 3a7dd06a - correct
         Events : 65852

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

 mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 6f619c94:6b307950:3fdba8c6:4f42b906
           Name : localhost.localdomain:0
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 20 12:14:37 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860150272 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766848 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6bda75d1:a7960438:b0b18851:bdc1e1d8

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul 13 15:53:28 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 2a25a397 - correct
         Events : 65852

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)



mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 6f619c94:6b307950:3fdba8c6:4f42b906
           Name : localhost.localdomain:0
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 20 12:14:37 2016
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860150272 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766848 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0f8d3e2f:409ba082:7369a795:614a1a07

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jul 13 15:53:28 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 44e19b3c - correct
         Events : 65852

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Is there any chace to recover data from the RAID?

Comment: If `sd{a,b,c,d}` are part of the MD device (please add the output of `/proc/mdstat` to your question) then `fdisk -l` on these devices does not make sense. You see old data (before the RAID creation).

Comment: Posted my /proc/mdstat

Comment: It's absolutely not clear which partitions your Fedora installation overwrote, so I'd just recreate RAID because there's little chance you'll be able to recover it. If you had data you need to restore, please try using R-Studio Undelete.

Comment: That's a lot of damage... what was on the RAID before? Just a filesystem, which one, or other things like LVM, LUKS, partitions, ...? Check `mdadm --examine` for the creation date, is it still the old RAID or did it get re-created as a whole too?

Comment: @roaima What makes you think the RAID has not started...?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Ah. I missed the `md0` line from `/proc/mdstat` entirely. I'll delete and rethink. Thanks

Comment: @frostschutz just added the  mdadm --examine data.
As you can see creation time left at the original. Update time is when I upgraded the OS.